# UITableViewAutomaticDimension To fit subviews

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, snapkit

My app has a table view with automatic sized row heights (*UITableViewAutomaticDimension* for heightForRow-Delegate-Function).
My custom cells have **subviews**, that can have **different sizes** (they contain an always different number of bar charts).

However, automatic cell height does not work to fit these different sizes of the subview of the tableview cell.

It **only** works, if I set a constraint (e.g. `make.top.equalTo(self).offset(300)` with snap kit) for the subview in the tableview cell - but since these subviews can have different sizes, this is not a clean solution.

Do you know a better approach?

Thanks!

Comment: @whoever voted down this question: of course you can vote this down, however, I would recommend leaving a comment  to lmk what you don’t like about this question - e.g. a link to a familiar question (which I did not find) or a hint if you don’t understand this question.

Comment: Agree, if u will downvote something at least leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:** on viewdidLoad (**not** in delegate):

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140 //this estimation will improve performance (can be omitted), set the +/- size of most cases.
```

Just don't override the cell height delegate.

**Second:**
      In your cell, u added that subView that contains chars. Add that subView constraints, but more important add a vertical spacing between that subview and the cell (this case the super view). Like the image.

[image]

If the subview height will set the cell height. Just make sure your chars inside the subView to set the subView height (with constraints).

[For more details, here there's a good step by step.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells)

Comment: @Pascal were u able to solve the problem? Maybe any doubt?